# openVPN for macOS, can I change the tunnel to wireGuard or IpSec?

Tags: networking, openvpn, ssl, tunnel, wireguard

I've got .ovpn file that configured to connect my openVPN client running on macOS to remote openVPN server for tunneling my network tranffic over there.

I was wondering why does my openVPN doesn't have network extension of its own. does it means that it uses some default network extension in macOS ? and what if I wish to change the tunnel from ssl to wireGaurd. it does have implementation which requires separated ad-hawk network extension. but how do i connect the openVPN to the utun interface that is created by wireGuard.

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Your question body is a little confusing so I will focus on the title.)

> openVPN for macOS, can I change the tunnel to wireGuard or IpSec?

No, you cannot. You must use an OpenVPN client to connect to an OpenVPN server. macOS does not have a OpenVPN client built-in. You must install it manually.

If you want a client with GUI support, I suggest looking into [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net/). I have never used it so I cannot help you set it up. They do have extensive documentation regarding compatibility with macOS in their website though.

A VPN client on macOS does not have to be implemented as a Network Extension. While Network Extensions provide a convenient high-level abstraction, programs are also free to directly access the native *utun* driver. This is what OpenVPN does.

If you want to modify how OpenVPN works, you’ll have to get and edit the [OpenVPN sources](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn) and then compile them yourself.

Comment: I have updated my answer. (I’ll remove my comments.)

Comment: Now it's much clearer. thanks ! but if it's not too much, perhaps you can point me in the code for where does the `directly access the native utun driver` is made (Just need a search word and i'll handle from here :-) )

Comment: Search for “utun”. It’s in `tun.c`. However, you won’t have access to unencrypted traffic there.